# #NaN error while trying to exponentiate a list in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to exponentiate a list in clojure. I wrote the following function (based on advice):

```
(defn myfunc [x n] (map #(Math/exp % n) x))
```

But when fed x = (list 'a 'b) and n = 2, instead of `(list 'a 'b 'a 'b)` it throws `##NaN ##NaN`

Any advice is appreciated. I think I am still missing some of the abstractions involved in functional programming languages.

Comment: Have you tried running `(Math/exp 'a 2)`?

Comment: Like this?(defn myfunc [x n] (map #(Math/exp 'a 2)))

feeding it the same inputs just returns #object [function]

Comment: No I mean, what are your expectations of that statement? The square of some object in JS is #NaN. You map over `'(a b)` and back you get your two #NaNs. Is the language you are comming from allowing you to do `[a b] ^ 2`?

Comment: I am not really coming from any language. I work in computational linguistics, and the idea is to solve problems like this:

Define L as a language containing a single sequence, L = {a}. Write a procedure in-L? that
takes a sequence (represented as a list), and decides if it is a member of the language L * .

Comment: Side note:  In Clojure, symbols like `'a` are mostly used as variables in the code. Since you are using something more like a Java enum, it is easier to use a keyword like `:a`. Then, your input list becomes a simple vector:  `[:a :b]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the confusion is with the term *exponentiation*. You can exponentiate numbers (multiply a number by itself to a given power), so I think you got advice on how to do that for all *numbers* of a given list.

In Clojure, the following works as you expect:

```clj
user=> (defn myfunc [x n] (map #(Math/pow % n) x))
#'user/myfunc
user=> (myfunc [1 2 3] 2)
(1.0 4.0 9.0)
```

But in your example, the list is a list of arbitrary names (not numbers) and I think the idea is that you want to repeat a list a number of times. I can think of a few options to implement it:

**Option 1**

`repeat` takes a number and an element and creates a sequence of said element repeated N times:

```clj
user=> (repeat 2 [1 2 3])
([1 2 3] [1 2 3])
```

Now we need to `concat`enate the results:

```clj
user=> (apply concat (repeat 2 [1 2 3]))
(1 2 3 1 2 3)
```

with that, we can define the following function:

```clj
(defn repeat-list [lst n]
  (apply concat (repeat n lst)))

(repeat-list (list 'a 'b 'c) 3)
;; => (a b c a b c a b c)
```

**Option 2**

You can create an *infinite* sequence of the elements of a given sequence with `cycle`:

```clj
;; We use 'take' here to get a *finite* number of elements:

user=> (take 10 (cycle [1 2 3]))
(1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

You can get the length of a sequence with `count`. For a list of size N and 2 repetitions, you want 2 * N elements, like this:

```clj
(defn repeat-list [lst n]
  (take (* n (count lst)) (cycle lst)))

(repeat-list (list 'a 'b 'c) 3)
;; => (a b c a b c a b c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes, you are right. That is exactly what I was trying to do! I appreciate the elegant clarification!